# WAMP and WordPress duplicator plug in doesn't work ( but works on MAMP )

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I use the duplicator WordPress plug in on MAMP and it works fine. When I do the same on WAMP I get a blob of errors.
[image]

Not sure how to remedy this.

Thank you.

edit , the same problem happens with XAMPP.

When I install WordPress by itself I do not have any problems.

Comment: Check your MAMP's `php.ini` against your WAMP's `php.ini` does MAMP have error reporting turned off but WAMP's does not? Also check that you are using the same version of PHP in both MAMP and WAMP

Comment: I commented out the offending plug in 'includes line' inside of wp-settings. It was // include_once( $mu_plugin );   This seems to get the site at least functional. But I am not sure about the relevance of that plug in.

Comment: Please include all Error messages as Text. Text in images are difficult to read, especially on mobile devices. Text in images also cannot by copy-pasted into search engines or editors.  You can `edit` to bring your post to SO guidelines.  More info can be found in the SO help section at [how to ask](https://StackOverflow.com.help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, you can try SO's sister site dedicated to WordPress at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment, don't have 50 rep yet. You should check what RiggsFolly said and also if

- in php/extensions, is php_curl checked?
- in Apache / modules, is the rewrite_module selected?

Maybe checking these options will solve your Duplicator problems. I'm also using Duplicator on Wamp without any issues.

Comment: I check both and restarted WAMP then re-ran the install of the wordpress instance... It did not work. Wordpress by itself installs just fine however.